# Adding BarButtonItem to a Modal Navigation View Controller

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, modalviewcontroller

I am presenting a modal navigation bar controller initialized with a root controller (which is a UITableViewController). When I, initialize the UINavigationBarController to present it modally, I am also adding a "Submit" button as a right bar button item. Everything is working fine (loading with root view and Modal presentation) However, the right button is not showing.
Posting the code below -

```
-(IBAction) presentAddLeaveRequestModally {
    AddLeaveRequestViewController *leaveRequestViewController = [[AddLeaveRequestViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:leaveRequestViewController];
    UIBarButtonItem *submitButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Submit" 
                                                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                     target:self 
                                                                     action:@selector(submitLeaveRequest)];
    navController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = submitButton;
    [self.homeTabBarController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
}
```

Any ideas if I am missing something obvious?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got the problem ... was adding rightBarButtonItem to navController's navigationItem ... I should be adding it to rootViewController's navigationItem in viewDidLoad.

```
UIBarButtonItem *submitButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Submit" 
                                                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                 target:self 
                                                                 action:@selector(submitLeaveRequest)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = submitButton;
```

Comment: Why can't we add before push or present the destinationViewController.?